# Input.getaxis("mouse Y") always return 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to make a Player Controller where you control it via WSAD or the arrow keys and it worked fine, but when I tried to add the part that registers the mouse movements on the X Y axes it went wrong...

Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") worked fine but Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") only returns zero no matter what I do... I have tried checking inside the Input Manager and there was nothing wrong, nor anything they're missing and I tried to Clear All PlayerPrefs and that did not work and I have also tried to restart my whole PC but it did not work either...

I do not know what to do and I have tried everything but without luck
If there are any of you who can help me it will be a great help
Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
private Rigidbody RB;
public int Speed = 250, JumpPawer = 250, RotationSpeed = 20, MaxAngle = 130;
private Animator A;
public GameObject Came;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    A = GetComponent<Animator>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //rotation
    transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0) * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
    if (Came.transform.eulerAngles.x + (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed) < MaxAngle) {
        print(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        Came.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
    }

    //controls
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        RB.velocity = transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        A.SetInteger("A", 1);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        RB.velocity = -transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        A.SetInteger("A", 1);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        RB.velocity = -transform.right * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        A.SetInteger("A", 2);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        RB.velocity = transform.right * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        A.SetInteger("A", 3);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        RB.velocity = Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * JumpPawer;
    }
    else
        A.SetInteger("A", 0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you changed the input manager’s settings, it isn’t a problem with the actual input. You could make sure the problem isn’t with the input system, by typing this (make sure it is out of the if statement you wrote before):

```
 print(Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y”);
```

If you do this and test the game, move your mouse up and down, then if you get a value, that then tells us, that the problem lies with the if statement, if it still returns 0, then there is a problem with unity. Here is what the if statement says:

```
if (Came.transform.eulerAngles.x + (Input.GetAxis("Mouse  Y") * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed) < MaxAngle) {
    print(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
    Came.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
}
```

Everything here is written out of my style (which is fine, it is just harder to understand), and there are no obvious errors, except for the code inside the parentheses. They say:

```
(Came.transform.eulerAngles.x + (Input.GetAxis("Mouse  Y") * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed) < MaxAngle)
```

The only thing I can spot is that you are only checking if the x rotation goes over. This won’t work the way you wanted to, because it wouldn’t be cow clamped when it goes under to. Since we can’t find the error, (someone might) we should just rewrite it.

Instead of putting an if statement, just use Mathf.Clamp(v, a, b); Mathf.Clamp clamps a number, v, so it doesn’t go under a, or over b. This is useful for a camera script, because you don’t want it to rotate behind the player. You should try this method:

```
void Camera()
{
    float MouseY = Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y”) * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
    Mathf.Clamp(MouseY, -89.5f, 89.5f);
    Came.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(MouseY, 0, 0);
    print(MouseY);
}
```

I removed the if statement entirely because we use Mathf.Clamp. Now we don’t have to test if it goes over or under because if this. You should multiply Time.deltaTime and RotationSpeed earlier, because if you multiply it later, it will go above/below the clamp. I then use local Euler angles, because if the player rig rotates, then so does the camera, and local means https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html. I then use the print statement just to test everything.

I hope this helps, if something doesn’t work, I’ll be sure to edit this post.